# How should windbg be configured to troubleshoot Microsoft reports(created in Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windbg

I have a report generating errors in the Output Window of Visual Studio.

I have tried hooking windbg in before the instance of ReportViewer is invoked so I could see examine the storage area for the data, particularly the names of columns in the datasource versus the data returned in the record set.

I have loaded extra parts, like this:

```
.load C:\debug\psscor2\psscor2\amd64\psscor2.dll
.load C:\debug\psscor2\psscor2\amd64\wow64exts.dll
```

I have also set the path for the symbols.

When windbg is setup this way, how can I locate the ReportViewer thread of interest and peek into its structure and data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking a very general question, so it's hard to give a specific answer, but here are a couple of points to get you started.

If this is a 32 bit process, you should get the 32 bit version of Debugging Tools for Windows and use that instead.

Also, if you drop psscor2.dll along side sos.dll (i.e. in the .NET framework path), you can just do

```
.loadby psscor2 mscorwks
```

(Replace `mscorwks` with `clr` if you're on .NET 4 or newer).

That will pick up psscor2 from the same location as mscorwks.dll. (Also, psscor is currently not available for .NET 4.5, so in that case you need to use sos.dll instead).

In order to inspect objects, you need to locate them on the heap. The `!dumpheap -stat` command will give you an overview of the entire heap. You can use `!dumpheap -mt <MT of type>` to dump objects of a specific type. You can find the MT for a given type using the `!name2ee` command.

Once you have locations of individual objects on the heap, you can use the `!do` (DumpObject) command to inspect these.

Comment: Also, the debug symbols should be loaded. I use the following command:.sympath+ SRV*c:\tmp*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Comment: You can use `.symfix` if you just want to point to the Microsoft public symbol server. Use `.sympath` for more control.

Comment: Actually, for .Net4 there's psscor4: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21255